# NSTimer repeats way to fast

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hallo i have a question about the NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval.
I set it up with an interval of two- however it repeats way more then every 2 seconds. Does anyone know what i do wrong?

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateAllHuds"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func updateAllHuds(){
    self.starTimer-=1
    self.builtTimer-=1
    self.gravityTimer-=1

    if self.powerStar.text == "1"{
        self.powerStar.removeFromParent()
        self.starActive = false
        self.activePowers-=1
        self.star.removeFromParent()
    }
```

...

Comment: you set it with 1, not 2

Comment: Thanks that was a spelling mistake. However its still way to fast it seems to be ticking something like every 0.1 second.

Comment: Where is the timer creation being called?  Any chance of it being called more than once?

Comment: Thanks that was it - I called it in my update() method and every game tick it was created new.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you seem to update ever 1 second:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateAllHuds"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

If you look at the docs you can see the first parameter "seconds" for the interval:

> The number of seconds between firings of the timer. If seconds is less than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1 milliseconds instead.

I would set this to 2 seconds as such:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateAllHuds"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Hope that helps for the NSTimer schedule.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I messed up there...However that was not my actual problem. Even if i set it to 1 it goes way to fast. It seems to be called something like every 0.1 second..

Comment: As per @phillipmills. Good that you have it sorted now.